# Using argument text in PHP Function

Tags: php, function, arguments

I am a little new to the PHP world and despite my googling and manual reading, I can't

I am currently (ethically!) scraping a website that has a number of different categories (let us call them 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma').

Currently, I go through these steps:

1. Load the file
2. Locate the correct table (php_siomple_dom)
3. Then go through the elements to grab the information.

   ```
   $alpha_one = $element -> find etc;
   $alpha_two = $element -> find etc;
   $alpha_n   = $element -> find etc;

   $beta_one  = $element -> find etc;
   $beta _two = $element -> find etc;
   $beta_n    = $element -> find etc;
   ```
4. All of the tables are the same for alpha, beta, gamma; thus I would like to write a function, but I am struggling with how to include the argument name in the variables I create. This was my idea, but it does not work.

   ```
   function grab($argument) {

       $argument . "_one" = $element -> find etc;
       $argument . "_two" = $element -> find etc;
       $argument . "_n"   = $element -> find etc;

   }
   ```

Thus, I could use:

`grab('alpha');`

`grab('beta');`

`grab('gamma');`

without having to write out the code for each table

I've looked into 'magic methods', but cannot swing it into working. I would really appreciate if some PHP wizard could shed some light upon this. Thank youu!

Comment: you mean : grab('alpha');

grab('beta');

grab('gamma'); ??

Comment: If you have a situation where you're numbering a series of variables, then you have a situation that calls for the use of an array instead

Comment: @KimAlexander yes, I did. I will update the question. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkBaker they actually aren't numbers, they are categories, but the hope of simplicity, I used numbers instead of my confusing category names. Thanks for the reply, though!

Comment: just simple note: you can do : $myvarname='anyVarNemIWant'; $$myvarname=5; echo $anyVarNameIWant;   output: 5 That allows you to use value of string var as a new (or existing) var name

Comment: This is a very good idea, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is rather pointless. the `$argument . "_one"` variable would exist **ONLY** within the function, and be destroyed when the function returns. You probably want something more like this:

```
function grab($argument) {
    $data = array();
    $data[$argument . "_one"] = ...
    $data[$argument . "_two"] = ...
    etc...
    return ($data);
}
```

Essentially: build an array with dynamic key names, based on your `$argument`, then return the entire array to the calling context.

Comment: Then `$data = grab('alpha'); echo $data['alpha_one'];`

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
function grab($argument) {
    ${$argument . "_one"} = $element -> find etc;
    ${$argument . "_two"} = $element -> find etc;
    ${$argument . "_n"}   = $element -> find etc;
}
```

Comment: ${$argument . "_one"}  :-) fix

Answer (score 0):

$argument only exists inside the function scope. It will not have any effect outside this function. If you're using a class you can create all possible variables (not recommended) and call:

```
$this->{$argument . "_one"} = ...
```

or store them in an array variable (best way):

```
$this->myArray[$argument . '_one'] = ...
```